# jQuery dataTables with colorbox popup

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, datatable, datatables

I'm using dataTables [Zero Configuration](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) but the data I fetch from MySQL database and when user click on any row, it open the details in [color box popup](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/). It is working perfect for me but when the data is more than 1000 records, then the loading take more around 1 minute and even more depending on the number of records. I know dataTables has [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) also and it loads very fast but I don't know how to use color box popup on that.

So can anyone please tell me if there is a way to improve my current code mentioned below so it can load faster? or help me find a way to use any popup with dataTables Server-side processing.

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="dataTable_1">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>USER ID</th>
   <th>USER NAME</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
   $sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` FROM `tbl_user` ORDER BY `user_id` DESC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $user_name = $row['user_name'];
    ?>
    <tr class="inline" href="#<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $user_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user_name; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <!-- COLOR BOX POPUP BEGIN -->
    <div style='display:none'>
    <div id='<?php echo $user_id; ?>'>
    USER DATA HERE IN THE POPUP
    </div> </div>
    <!-- COLOR BOX POPUP END -->
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to initialise your pop-ups after each draw using `fnDrawCallback` (http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks), perhaps a work up on JSFiddle might help.

Comment: @annoyingmouse the issue is not just color box. Even if I remove the popup script completely, it still take so much time to load.

Comment: I suggested the callback to reinitialise the color box after data had been retrieved from the server...